# Xamarin iOS LaunchScreen with gradient background

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How do I add a gradient background to a LaunchScreen storyboard? I read in the ios document that LaunchScreen storyboards do not support custom classes, and if I am correct Storyboards directly don't support background gradients.

Is it possible to achieve this? If we can, it will be great if someone could give me an idea.

Comment: Why is it marked as "not a programming question"? I really could not add any code to this question, because it's do with storuboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** run code or use custom classes in LaunchScreen.storyboard. You can refer to [Launch Screens](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/) on this.

> For a storyboard to be used as a launch screen it must include only simple, built-in UI elements and cannot do any calculations or be based off of a custom class.

So, the best solution is to add a gradient image in it. Just notice that the image needs to adapt to all the iPhone screens.

Comment: We can add custom controls(Uiview) to storyboard for sure.

Comment: UIView is not a custom control，it is system's.

Comment: I get that. What I meant is we can add custom controls to storyboard that inherits UIView.

Comment: Ok. Now reading the docs, it states that we cannot add custom class to LaunchScreens.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.